# What is a rational way of factoring polynomials?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Consider the following polynomial $$P_x:=x^4+1$$
I want to represent it as a product of two polynomials with **real coefficients** of grade $2$. I have done this using, call it, a brute force method.
$$x^4+1 \stackrel{!}{=} (x^2+bx+c)(x^2+dx+e) \Longleftrightarrow\\
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ll}
d+b=0 \\ 
c+e+db=0 \\ 
be+cd=0\\
ce=1
\end{array}
\right.$$

Having solved this, which took some time, I came up with $$x^4+1=(x^2-\sqrt 2x+1)(x^2+\sqrt2x+1)$$
Is there another more solid method of factoring polynomials with real coefficients? I also was thinking about polynomial division, but seems to be as much time-consuming.

Comment: Note that you can also obtain that factorisation as follows: $$x^4+1 = (x^4+2x^2+1)-2x^2 = (x^2+1)^2-(\sqrt{2}x)^2 = (x^2+1-\sqrt{2}x)(x^2+1+\sqrt{2}x).$$

Comment: Another way of getting this is to identify the fourth roots of $-1$ and take them in complex conjugate pairs.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese clever notice, but I am looking for something more general, that can be applied to any polynomial. Like Mark Bennet's suggestion

Comment: It is not clear what *general* problem you pose. Are you considering the general problem of factoring any real polynomial into real factors?

Comment: @BillDubuque yes, but in two or more real factors

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}x^{4n}+a^{4k}&=\Big(x^{4n}+2a^{2k}x^{2n}+a^{4k}\Big)-2a^{2k}x^{2n}\\&=\Big(x^{2n}+a^{2k}\Big)^2-\Big(\sqrt2~a^kx^n\Big)^2\\&=\Big(x^{2n}-\sqrt2~a^kx^n+a^{2k}\Big)\Big(x^{2n}+\sqrt2~a^kx^n+a^{2k}\Big).\end{align}$$